# Codeigniter search just reloads page

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i have set up a MVC project to search a database and display results.

On click of search button the page just reloads itself. Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Controller

```
  public function search()
{
$txt = $this->input->post('search', true);
$this->load->model('post');
$data['searchbox'] = $this->post->search($txt);        //search is function on model
$this->load->view('/search', $data);
}
```

Model

```
    public function search($txt)
{
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * From st_posts");
        return $query->result();  
}
```

Form View

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('/search');?>" method = "post">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name = "search" id="search" class="form-control" /> 
        </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" value = "Search" class="btn btn-primary center-block" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

results view

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>title</th>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach($searchbox as $row)?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </table>
```

Comment: does your `<?php echo site_url('membership/membership_area/search');?>`  is setting the form action correctly and pointing to the correct controller ? try setting the form action manually.

Comment: $this->load->view('/search', $data); instead use $this->load->view('search', $data); .... REMOVE / before search

Comment: also echo site_url('/search');?> here you specified only controller, after that there should be method. something like site_url('/search/search'); 
url is always like /controller/method

Comment: So got a little further : now we have Unable to load the requested file: pages/membership_area/search.php

Answer (score 0):

You should always use model just for query on database like delete, search, add, update data etc. I always applied like this just try to update your code in this form:

**Controller**: 
That say that we have a function on controller something like this:

```
public function search()
{
    $txt = $this->input->post('search', true);
    $this->load->model('Your model that you want to search from');
    $data['searchbox'] = $this->yourModel->search($txt);        //search is function on model
    $this->load->view('pages/membership_area/search', $data);
```

}

**Model**:
That say that we have also a function like this on Model:

```
public function search($txt)
{
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * From TableName");
        return $query->result();  
}
```

**View**:

```
<?php foreach($searchbox as $row)?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
</tr>
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Hey thanks, so i added what you have put above and im gettign a 404 error on submit

Comment: I don't know how are named and structured your files. Maybe the problem could be on controller when you load view change the path like this: For examples: if you have a file called info.php on view folder like this: view/info. Just add path on load view('info', data)

Comment: updated the question with code, still getting a 404 on submit, thanks